# Replace value of an environment variable declared in a file

Tags: bash, envsubst

There is a file `env.sh`, which defines environment variables:

```
$cat env.sh
export var1=1
export var2=2
```

I want to replace the value of `var1` inside of the file with `3`, so that

```
$cat env.sh
export var1=3
export var2=2
```

Is there way to do it without string/regexp matching magic?

I read a lot about `envsubst`, but still was not able to figure out how to apply it to the task.

Comment: I'm confused.  Can you not just edit the file and replace the value?  What distro are you using?  You may also be able to edit a `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and simply overwrite the value of `var1`

Comment: @jasonmclose I could. However this step should be a bash command. The value of var1 is generated as part of the process and as soon as it is generated it needs to be replaced in a file.

Comment: Not very elegant, append a new line: `echo "export var1=3" >> env.sh`

Comment: Thank you, that is an option. I want to have only one definition of var1 in the file though

Comment: You don't want to do string/regexp stuff.  Are you opposed to deleting the content at line X and then appending to the end the new value?  If you always know the line number in the file that var1 is located, you can just delete that line and then append the new value to the end.

Comment: This is just a file-editing task. Use an editor like `ed`, `sed`, or `ex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a scriptable editor like `ed`:

```
$ cat env.sh
export var1=1
export var2=2
$ printf  '/var1=/s/=.*/var1=3/\nw\n' | ed env.sh
28
28
$ cat env.sh
export var1=3
export var2=2
```

Answer (score 2):

Without regex in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh
export var1=3
declare -p var1 > env.sh
declare -p var2 >> env.sh
```

Output to env.sh:

```
declare -x var1="3"
declare -x var2="2"
```

`declare -x` is synonymous with `export`.